# Result of linux 'ls -lisa' command

Tags: linux, ls

What is the meaning of the second column in ls -lisa command ?

```
ls -lisa
total 12
280187 0 -rw-rw-r--  2 embedded embedded    0 Apr  3 02:05 a.txt
```

- The total command means the number of allocated 512-Byte blocks.
- The first column shows the I-Node number.(280187)
- The 3rd column shows the permissions.(-rw-rw-r--)
- The 4rd column shows the number of hard-links for the inode.(2)
- The 5th column shows user and group.(embedded embedded)
- The 6th column shows the size of the file.(0)
- The 7th column shows the date of the last change(Apr  3 02:05)
- The last column shows the name of the file(a.txt)

But i don't know for what the second column stands for?

Comment: have you figured out what the 2nd column means?

Comment: I tracked it down to be about the number of blocks ([code here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/d6125af095c9553f38cba0696f15158f5abe4ecc/src/ls.c#L4332-L4346)). But it's still unclear to me how it's exactly calculated. By default, the number of blocks is close to file_size / block_size (1024), but it doesn't look always the case. Fyi, the file_size is printed at [code here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/d6125af095c9553f38cba0696f15158f5abe4ecc/src/ls.c#L4397-L4411)

Answer (score 3):

The second column is the result of the -s (--size) option, it represents the allocated size of the file, always a multiple of the allocation unit.
http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/ls1.html

Comment: then what's the diff between the 2nd column and the 6th column?

Comment: The 2nd column is the number of blocks allocated for the file. The 6th column is the number of bytes contained in the file. You can check the block size for the partition with `blockdev --getbsz`. As an example, my `.lesshst` has 4 blocks allocated and my block size is 512. That makes 2048 bytes allocated. The file itself is 123 only bytes. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17779363/1106272

Answer (score 0):

The second column in your ouptut prints the size of the file.When you had a multiple options together, It would have confused you.

```
ls -lisa
280187 0 -rw-rw-r--  2 embedded embedded    0 Apr  3 02:05 a.txt
```

The option is

```
   -s, --size
          print the allocated size of each file, in blocks
```